# Yii2/Bootstrap NavBar menu - keep an item always visible

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, yii2, navbar

I have an Yii2 application with NavBar menu up top, which looks something like that:

```
echo Nav::widget([
                'options' => ['class' => 'navbar-nav '],
                'items' => [
                    ['label' => 'Home', 'url' => ['/site/index']],
                    ['label' => 'About', 'url' => ['/site/about']],
                    ['label' => 'Contact', 'url' => ['/site/contact']],
...
```

In fact, in my code I have `'encodeLabels' => false` and I have images instead of text in the labels but that is not relevant.

This behaves exactly as intended on small screen - on small and extra small devices the links disappear, the 'hamburger' icon pops up and if you click on it, you get a drop down with all the links.

What I want to do is always keep a couple of links outside of the 'hamburger' menu and not include them in the drop down menu. For example, the "Home" and "About" links need to stay in the menu, visible at each level even when the screen becomes too small and everything else is free to go inside the dropdown menu.

I did few attempts to stuff them in the `NavBar::begin` part of the code with no success, besides, I think there should be an easier way to do that. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You should replace `NavBar` widget with plain html to customize bootstrap `navbar`:

```
<nav role="navigation" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header navbar-right pull-right">
      <ul class="nav pull-left">
        <li class="navbar-text pull-left">User Name</li>
        <li class="dropdown pull-right">
          <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" style="color:#777; margin-top: 5px;" class="dropdown-toggle">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>
            <b class="caret"></b>
          </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li>
              <a href="/users/id" title="Profile">Profile</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="/logout" title="Logout">Logout </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <button type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" class="navbar-toggle">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="visible-xs-block clearfix"></div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
        <li><a href="/news">News</a></li>
        <li><a href="/Shop">Shop</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="/locator">Locator</a></li>
        <li><a href="/extras">Extras</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gnxqpoo0/1/)

Comment: How its going to highlight active menu item?

Comment: @RNKushwaha You can use current controller name `\Yii::$app->controller->id` to set active class for menu item.

Comment: Can you provide a working example? How to check if current url is matching one in our html ?

Answer (score 0):

Setting options in item   allows add class or  style for specific item. eg style='display block;'.
This allows you to avoid having to manage all the navbar with plain html code

```
'items' => [
                [
                    'label' => 'Home', 
                    'url' => ['/site/index'],
                    'options' => ['class' => 'yourClass'
                                  'style' => 'display: block!important;'],
                ],
                ['label' => 'About', 'url' => ['/site/about']],
                ........................
```

Comment: Hm, I've tried that but it seems that it doesn't do any justice. The link still gets pushed inside the dropdown menu where it is, in fact, displayed as block but it's still inside which is what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: change the display properly based on what you need. Mine was just  an example for avoiding plain text manage of navbar (try inline) o try with firebugs and the apply the correct result

Comment: By default the <li> items that I'm dealing with have position: relative and display: block and no particular changes have much of an effect. In fact, the 'hamburger' button takes the space above the containing <ul> so even if I 'detach' an item from the list, the most it could go upwards would still not be enough to push it as high as I need. It's a good tip to play around with the CSS and rewrite it somehow but at the end of the day, looking at how things are right now, it might be easier to just go with the plain html :(